# How to change a character-set for a datatype DATETIME in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, character-encoding

I am trying to run a query which includes comparing an `unicode` string with some of the columns. For this, I need to change **character-set** and **character-encoding** for a column of type `DATETIME`. But when I execute following query:

```
ALTER TABLE licenses CHANGE expires_at expires_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I get an error as:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci' at line 1
```

But for the following query (which alters **character-set** of a column of type `VARCHAR`) works perfectly fine:

```
ALTER TABLE customers CHANGE DEFAULT NULL name name VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**How can I change the character-set for a mysql column of type `DATETIME`?**

Comment: Datetime are not characters data-type so u cant change its CHARACTER-SET

Comment: Thanks a lot @Melon for immediate response. But now I am trying to use `LIKE` operation on a `unicode` string and a `DATETIME` column. So how can I address this situation?

Comment: Anyways, the one option that I can think of right now is to change the **filter-query** to `ASCII` (as `DATETIME` column won't be containing `unicode` characters anyway).

Comment: That works as expected. So I am using the `original_filter_query` for filtering `unicode` enabled columns, and using `ascii_filter_query` (converted from `original_filter_query`, ignoring `unicodes`) on `datetime` column.